# When and How first folder was created?

Tags: directory

Everybody know that in computer everything is in binary at last. So just i want to know that how was the first program created for folder? It can be in binary or assembly whatever language I dont know which language was used for creating folder. any Help?

Comment: What do you mean by "folder" in this context ?

Comment: Directory in computer - A folder/Directory is a storage space that many files can be placed into to group them together and organize the computer.

Comment: OK - early computers did not even have file systems - what era are you talking about ?

Comment: I dont know, but "directory" is exist till today that means it was definitely created earlier, it did not automatically created by computer, obviously someone was created by binary(0/1) or assembly.

Comment: For directories (aka "folders") you need a hierarchical file system. [This article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(file_systems)) claims that Multics was the first OS with a hierarchical file system, in the 1960s.

Answer (score 0):

A folder, also called a directory, is a concept of hierarchical file system. In a hierarchical file system, file and folders are organized as nodes of a tree. Every node can be a folder or a file. Every node that is a folder can have sub-folders(sub-directories) and files as child nodes. So, the first program created for a folder used the tree data structure to implement a hierarchical file structure where the folder was a node.

[Multics was the first operating system to provide a hierarchical file system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics#Novel_ideas) Multics was written in PL/I, Assembly Language. So, by extension the first folder was also implemented in PL/I and Assembly Language.